# how to delete table located on other server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(myserver, 'delete mytable
                          SELECT null')
```

but this does not work - I get this error:

> Cannot process the object " delete mytable SELECT null
>   The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "myserver" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Any help?

Comment: *does not work* - how exactly?? Are you getting an error? If so, please **post it here** so we can see, too !

Comment: To add to @marc_s comment, you might find more success in finding an answer if you add a tag to more specific tag than sql like mysql, sql-server.

Comment: I use sql server and this is the error 
Cannot process the object " 
delete mytable
SELECT null

the OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "myserver" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Comment: Does the user that connects to the linked server have enough permissions?

Comment: yes I have all the permissions(sa user)

Comment: Linked Server connections have user mappings (created via `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`) to convert local user credentials to different user credentials on the remote server. You might have sa locally, but you also might have guest remotely.